# hosting libraries in corporate gitlab

Tags: python, scala, npm, gitlab

What are the recommended ways to host Scala (Play) libraries (or Python or Npm packages) in the **internal** (corporate) GitLab to eliminate any external dependencies (due to the security or failure concerns)?

Comment: We use [Nexus Repository Manager](https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository) and fits perfectly fine to our use case, you can check it out, it has also good documentations to get started, and is easy to use.

Comment: This is an opinionated question. Also you should focus more on which part you are struggling with, this is a broad topic: is Gitlab registry the focus? Gitlab CI? The package manager tooling? ...